# How to clean a dataset having string values?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am working on a dataset where few values in one of the column are string. due to that i am getting error while performing operations on dataset.

sample dataset:-

```
1.99    LOHARU  0.3 2   0   2   0.3 5   2   0   2   2
1.99    31  0.76    2   0   2   0.76    5   2   7.48    4   2
1.99    4   0.96    2   0   2   0.96    5   2   9.45    4   2
1.99    14  1.26    4   0   2   1.26    5   2   0   2   2
1.99    NUH 0.55    2   0   2   0.55    5   2   0.67    2   2
1.99    99999   0.29    2   0   2   0.29    5   2   0.06    2   2
```

full dataset can be found here:- https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/audit-data?select=trial.csv

I need to found the missing values and outlier in the dataset. below is the code i am using to find missing values:-

```
#Replacing zeros and 99999 with `np.NaN`

dataset[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]=dataset[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]].replace(99999,np.NaN)

#if 12,14 and 17 can have zeroes then
dataset[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,16]]=dataset[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,16]].replace(0,np.NaN)

print(Dataset.isnull().sum())
```

but this doesn't replace 99999 with NaN

and to find outlier:-

i am calculating zscore

```
import scipy.stats as stats
array = Dataset.values
Z=stats.zscore(array)
```

but it gives me below error:

```
- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: I don't see any 99999 in the raw data

Comment: 99999 is added manually in location_id column

Comment: Did you replace it with "99999" or 99999? i.e. string or number?

Comment: replaced with number- 99999

Comment: Which columns do you want the z-score for? Zscore for "LOCATION_ID" makes no sense

Comment: I am trying to get zscore for all the columns

Comment: so, do you mean I need to perform operations on other columns except Location_ID ?

Comment: wondering if there is anyway to deal with these string values?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to convert columns to numeric data type where possible:

```
dff = df.replace({0: np.nan, 99999: np.nan}).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
zscores = (dff-dff.mean())/dff.std()

>>> zscores
   Sector_score  LOCATION_ID    PARA_A  ...  Detection_Risk  Audit_Risk  Risk
0           NaN          NaN -1.008963  ...             NaN   -0.726564   NaN
1           NaN     1.074450  0.191355  ...             NaN    1.034549   NaN
2           NaN    -0.903515  0.713232  ...             NaN    1.507377   NaN
3           NaN    -0.170935  1.496048  ...             NaN   -0.473018   NaN
4           NaN          NaN -0.356616  ...             NaN   -0.621491   NaN
5           NaN          NaN -1.035057  ...             NaN   -0.720853   NaN
```

Note: Columns that have the same value for all rows have no standard deviation and are hence showing as NaN.

###### Input df:

```
>>> df
   Sector_score LOCATION_ID  PARA_A  ...  Detection_Risk  Audit_Risk  Risk
0          1.99      LOHARU    0.30  ...             0.5      0.2920     0
1          1.99          31    0.76  ...             0.5      0.9088     0
2          1.99           4    0.96  ...             0.5      1.0744     1
3          1.99          14    1.26  ...             0.5      0.3808     0
4          1.99         NUH    0.55  ...             0.5      0.3288     0
5          1.99       99999    0.29  ...             0.5      0.2940     0
```